# I'm trying to sort and set a string to see if it matches the alphabet. If yes i want to return True but it returns False

Tags: python, string, function, sorting, return

```
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    return ''.join(sorted(set(str1.lower()))) == alphabet
ispangram("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
```

the output of the `''.join(sorted(set(str1.lower())))` is `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '`

there is a space in the end and this is why it's not matching the alphabet string and returning false.

how can i fix it ? i'm new to this language so I probably don't have the skillset to solve it, it might be very simple so thanks for the helpers :)

Comment: What is `str1`?

Comment: The space must be in the argument you're giving to the function.

Comment: @MarkMeyer edited it now , sorry. it's the string in the function call

Answer (score 3):

The thing it seems that you *really* want to know is if every element in alphabet is in the string. If the string can contain punctuation and spaces, you probably don't want those interfering with your test. What you can do is a set of the test string and alphabet and see if the test string set is a superset of the alphabet using the [`>=` operator](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issuperset)

```
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    return set(str1.lower()) >= set(alphabet)


ispangram("The brown quick fox jumps over the lazy dog") 
# true
ispangram("The brown (quick) fox jumps over the lazy dog?")
#true

ispangram("The quick fox jumps over the lazy dog")
#false
```

This has the added benefit of avoiding the sort.

Comment: I know it must be really simple, but what is the & sign do?

Comment: @liamlasry `&` is the [intersection operator](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) for sets. If returns elements common to both.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this issue easily with the function **strip()**, this function helps to delete additional spaces in your output, like this:

```py
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    output = ''.join(sorted(set(str1.lower()))).replace(" ","")
    return output == alphabet
```

You can read about the **strip()** function and other buit-in functions in the [Python Official Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

**Edit:**
As pointed out, since blank spaces could be in other parts rather than just at the beginning of the end, I am editing to use the **replace()** function.

Let me know if this helps! :D

Comment: This assumes the space will always be at the beginning or end.

Comment: In that sense, let me change that for you!

Comment: so just to make it clear. strip is deleting spaces only from the end or the beggining?

Answer (score 2):

You should remove anything that isn't in the alphabet first.

```
def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    set1 = set(filter(lambda c: c in alphabet, str1.lower()))
    return ''.join(sorted(set1)) == alphabet
```

Comment: Ah sorry for the previous comment spam. An additional `sorted` makes this work for Pythons less than 3.8.

Comment: @usr2564301 Why do you say less than 3.8? It would make this work for 3.8 as well.

Comment: @HeapOverflow: well... I was assuming Barmar is on the latest – I am not, in my current IDE – and he must of tested it, right?

Comment: @HeapOverflow You're my testers :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in `str1`.
You should try this:

`''.join(sorted(set("".join(str1.split()).lower())))`

That removes all white-spaces from `str1` first. Then does what you already did.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your current test: test if all characters in `alphabet` occur in `str1`:

```py
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    return (all(char in str1.lower() for char in alphabet))

print (ispangram ('Watch “Jeopardy!”, Alex Trebek’s fun TV quiz game.'))
```

[`all(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) returns `True` if all of `x` elements evaluate to true. `char in str1.lower() for char in alphabet` iterates over `alphabet` and tests if each of its characters (put in `char`) occur in `str1.lower`. As soon as one fails, `all` returns `False`, `True` otherwise.